# C# Uri? vs. Nullable<Uri>

Tags: c#, .net

I've always known in C# that you can represent nullable types in multiple ways, with the difference often being described as "syntactic sugar".  For example, the following...

```
// Case 1
int? nullableIntegerVar01;
// Case #2 - 
System.Nullable<int> nullableIntegerVar02;
// Case #3 - 
Uri? nullableUriVar01;
// Case #4 
System.Nullable<Uri> nullableUriVar02;
```

Oddly, case #4 above does not compile and throw the following error.

"Error  CS0453  The type 'Uri' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'"

I understand the error, I do not understand the reasoning - I expected these two methods of defining nullable types to be interchangeable.

Further, the following does not work.

```
var testType = typeof(Uri);
var testNullableType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(testType);
```

Can anyone provide insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For value types, such as int or structs (that normally can never be null), x? is equivalent to `Nullable<x>` (syntactic sugar), and it creates a new type. For reference types such as Uri the ? only serves as an annotation, it doesn't create a new type (these can be null regardless of the presence of the ? marker).

Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: Thank you. I just reviewed some IL and realized that "Uri" and "Uri?" both compile to "[System.Runtime]System.Uri". With the new nullable feature enabled, having to explicitly define reference types as nullable (i.e. Uri? methodParam) skewed my thinking a bit of what Uri? actually represented.

Comment: Keep in mind that the nullable annotations on reference types are purely a compile-time feature.  They do not offer any runtime protection or validation.